# I want call these two methods of max() and min() to return the max and min integer from array

Tags: java, methods

I want to have a java code that takes user input for an integer array and that finds the max integer via a max method and min integer via a min method, but I don't know how to call methods in main. I have tried but can't figure it out. I am a new learner of java and I know it's very basic. I would be very thankful to get a nice answer. Please do not get offended:)

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class IntegerCheck {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count, max, min, i;
    int[] inputArray = new int[500];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
    count = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter " + count + " elements");
     
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        inputArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    } 
}


static int max() {
int count = 0, max, i;
int[] inputArray = new int[500];
max = inputArray[0];
for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if(inputArray[i] > max)
        max = inputArray[i];
}
return i;}


static int min() {
int count = 0, min, i;
int[] inputArray = new int[500];
min = inputArray[0];
for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if(inputArray[i] < min)
        min = inputArray[i];
}
return i;}}
```

Comment: You're returning i from max(). Unfortunately i will always equal count. I would think you'd want to return max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input integer array as input to the functions, you can pass them as parameters in the function.
Also, if you pass the array in the function, you need not define another array in the function. Right now, the array used in the function has different values from the one that was inputted by the user in the `main()` function.

So you could have something like

```
public class IntegerCheck {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count, max, min, i;
    int[] inputArray = new int[500];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
    count = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter " + count + " elements");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      inputArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    int maxInArray = max(inputArray, count);
    int minInArray = min(inputArray, count);
    System.out.println("Max: "+ maxInArray);
    System.out.println("Min: "+ minInArray);
  }

  static int max(int[] inputArray, int count) {
    int max, i;
    max = inputArray[0];
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
      if (inputArray[i] > max) {
        max = inputArray[i];
      }
    }
    return max;
  }

  static int min(int[] inputArray, int count) {
    int min, i;
    min = inputArray[0];
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
      if (inputArray[i] < min) {
        min = inputArray[i];
      }
    }
    return min;
  }
}
```

Also, in the `min` and `max` functions, you return `I` (upper case i) which is different from `i`. Note that variables are case sensitive in java

Comment: It's not returning the correct answer :) Thanks

Comment: The answer addresses the syntax requested for in the question, not the semantic. There are still semantic errors. For example, count is currently defined as 0 in min & max. You could pass that in the function :)

Comment: Well, I have updated the answer to pass count as a parameter. Good luck !